# Is there a way to sync Lion's Reading List across two or more Macs?

Tags: macos

For example: if I add a URL to the Reading List on my iMac, can it then be synced to the Reading List on my MacBook? It does not appear so even though I believe Reading List is going to sync with iOS 5 devices? (if it is not officially supported, is there a hack to do so)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syncing between all macs, pcs and iOS devices will be possible when iCloud is released to the public along with iOS 5.

Comment: If you want something that works across Macs and iOS devices now, you can look at Instapaper. Also works with Kindle.

Comment: Well yeah ik but Ken Clark was talking about reading list specifically (possibly because it's elegance in integration into Safari) so i didn't even bother listing other alternatives

Comment: Thanks. That was what I was hoping to hear, but wasn't sure Mac-to-Mac was part of the update. @reaganing Thanks for the note. I am syncing via Instapaper now which is a great service and product.